# Trouble with gRPC connection to the server

Tags: python, client-server, grpc

I'm trying to connect a client to a server, using the following gRPC code.

```py
#greet_pb2_grpc.py
class GreetServiceStub(object):
    """service here refers to the method contract the client must fulfill in order to call this service
    """

    def __init__(self, channel):
        """Constructor.

        Args:
            channel: A grpc.Channel.
        """
        self.Greeting = channel.unary_unary(
                '/GreetService/Greeting',
             request_serializer=greet__pb2.GreetingRequest.SerializeToString,
                response_deserializer=greet__pb2.GreetingResponse.FromString,
                )
```

```py
#main.py
import grpc
from greet_pb2_grpc import GreetServiceStub

def main():
    channel = grpc.insecure_channel("localhost:8000")
    client = GreetServiceStub(channel)
    client.Greeting()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxx/projects/grpc/grpc-client/grpc-client/greet/client.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/xxxx/projects/grpc/grpc-client/grpc-client/greet/client.py", line 8, in main
    client.Greeting()
TypeError: _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.__call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'
```

What is this required positional argument that is being mentioned?

UPDATE: Here is the proto file used to generate the gRPC code.

```
syntax = "proto3"; 

option go_package = "grpc-client/proto/greet";

// service here refers to the method contract the client must fulfill in order to call this service
service GreetService{
    rpc Greeting(GreetingRequest) returns (GreetingResponse){}
}

// The request message contains the user's name
message GreetingRequest{
    string name = 1;
}

// The response message contains the greetings
message GreetingResponse{
    string message = 1;
}
```

greet_pb2.py does not contain any `GreetingRequest` interface.

```py
# greet_pb2.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by the protocol buffer compiler.  DO NOT EDIT!
# source: greet.proto
"""Generated protocol buffer code."""
from google.protobuf.internal import builder as _builder
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
# @@protoc_insertion_point(imports)

_sym_db = _symbol_database.Default()




DESCRIPTOR = _descriptor_pool.Default().AddSerializedFile(b'\n\x0bgreet.proto\"\x1f\n\x0fGreetingRequest\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x01(\t\"#\n\x10GreetingResponse\x12\x0f\n\x07message\x18\x01 \x01(\t2A\n\x0cGreetService\x12\x31\n\x08Greeting\x12\x10.GreetingRequest\x1a\x11.GreetingResponse\"\x00\x42\x19Z\x17grpc-client/proto/greetb\x06proto3')

_builder.BuildMessageAndEnumDescriptors(DESCRIPTOR, globals())
_builder.BuildTopDescriptorsAndMessages(DESCRIPTOR, 'greet_pb2', globals())
if _descriptor._USE_C_DESCRIPTORS == False:

  DESCRIPTOR._options = None
  DESCRIPTOR._serialized_options = b'Z\027grpc-client/proto/greet'
  _GREETINGREQUEST._serialized_start=15
  _GREETINGREQUEST._serialized_end=46
  _GREETINGRESPONSE._serialized_start=48
  _GREETINGRESPONSE._serialized_end=83
  _GREETSERVICE._serialized_start=85
  _GREETSERVICE._serialized_end=150
# @@protoc_insertion_point(module_scope)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import then provide the RPC method with the request message.

You don't include the proto but, from the code, it will be something like:

```
service Greet {
  rpc Greeting(GreetingRequest) returns (GreetingResponse);
}

message GreetingRequest {
  # Complete as appropriate
}
message GreetingResponse {
  # Complete as appropriate
}
```

And so, you'll need:

```py
import greet_pb2

channel = grpc.insecure_channel("localhost:8000")
client = GreetServiceStub(channel)

request = greet_pb2.GreeetingRequest(
    # Complete as appropriate
)
response = client.Greeting(request)
```

Comment: It seems like GreetingRequest is not generated. Perhaps the proto file that I provided is incomplete.

Comment: Do you have a `greet_pb2.py` file? It should have been generated by `protoc` as a result of the `--python_out=${PWD}` flag. You need it for the protobuf messages and `--grpc_python_out=${PWD}` to generate the gRPC bindings.

Comment: Yes, but it does not contain any GreetingRequest interface.

Comment: It does, it's just not very clear that it does. Python's generated code is dynamically generated at runtime and so the content of `greet_pb2.py` is... confusing. You'll notice that the file includes e.g. `_GREETINGREQUEST` and this is a reference to the `GreetingRequest` message that should (!) be available as `greet_pb2.GreetingRequest`. If you're using Visual Studio Code, you'll likely be told this doesn't exist but Code is incorrect and the code should work.